# What can I do with this .git folder?

Tags: git

I seem to have lost some projects, and, in going through all my data, the only thing I've found for a few projects is a `.git` directory with the following contents. Is it at all possible to recover my repo from this? I don't see any actual code anywhere.

[image: git directory contents]

Comment: I could be bare repo. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456923/why-am-i-getting-the-message-fatal-this-operation-must-be-run-in-a-work-tree).

Answer (score 0):

The `.git` directory contains your actual git repository, including files, logs, everything. If it's undamaged, then it means that only your working copy was deleted. You should be able to `git reset` your way out of this.

Open a terminal, change to the directory that contains the `.git` directory, and run

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

Whatever was last committed should return.

Comment: That tells me `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`, which makes sense, because im trying to restore my working tree somehow. I am able to see my commit history with `git log` but thats about the only git command that succeeds.

Comment: You're probably screwed, then. Restore from backup.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no backup :/

These were all old archived projects. so it s not a huge loss. but still disappointing.